# Scalas too verbose

Tags: scala, sbt

When running scalas scripts, the first output line is something like:

`[info] Set current project to root-5a8b3b7852543088d088 (in build file:/Users/username/bin/~/.sbt/boot/5a8b3b7852543088d088/)`

This does not give much useful information and is more of a distraction. Also, if I want to pipe the output of the script to another script, I would have to filter this line as well.

Is there a flag or some other way to stop sbt from printing this line?

**Edit:**

For now, as a workaround, I am piping the output of the script into `tail` to drop the first line:

```
exec java $JAVA_OPTS -jar "$LAUNCHJAR" "$@" | tail -n +2
```

Comment: Whether there is or not, `sbt` is in no way required to run a scala program.  You can just compile it and invoke it directly.

Comment: @IanMcLaird You are right, but when scripting in scala I think it is useful to be able to declare dependencies for the script. Scalas (sbt scripts) allows to do it nicely.

Comment: Sure, but you can have sbt compile your source into a monolithic jar that contains all the dependencies, which is directly runnable with the `java` command.  At that point, users of your script don't even need *scala* installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's echoing this setting:

```
onLoadMessage := ""
```